# io for non associative containers of std::string

Tags: c++, string, templates

I want to provide a generic line based IO for containers of std::string in a library.
Line based since the strings may contain spaces.
The following code seems to work fine but I'm not sure whether this is the best way to go or whether it creates some ambiguities, I'm failing to grasp.

```
#define boostForeach BOOST_FOREACH

template< template<typename ELEM, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<ELEM> > class Container >
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, Container<std::string>const & container){
  boostForeach(std::string const& str, container) {
    o << str << "\n";
  }
  return o;
}

template< template<typename ELEM, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<ELEM> > class Container >
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Container<std::string>& container){
  container.clear();
  std::string buf;
  while(getline(in, buf)) {
    if(buf.empty()) break; //stop if empty line found to separate map from other data
    container.insert(container.end(),buf);
  }
  return in;
}
```

So the question is: Is this safe and sound ?

Comment: You may want to [take a look here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: @netcoder: Nice! Didn't know about this one and will definitely give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the output algorithm using `std::copy()`:

```
std::copy(container.begin(),
    container.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(o, "\n"));
```

You might use an input iterator for paragraph input, i.e., multiple lines separated by blank lines:

```
class istream_paragraph_iterator: public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,std::string>{
    std::istream* stream;
    std::string line;
public:

    istream_paragraph_iterator() : stream(0) {}

    istream_paragraph_iterator(std::istream& stream) : stream(&stream) {++*this; //get the first element
    }

    std::string operator*() const {
        return line;
    }

    const std::string* operator->() const {
        return &line;
    }

    istream_paragraph_iterator& operator++() {
        if (stream && (!std::getline(*stream, line) || line.empty()))
            stream = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    istream_paragraph_iterator operator++(int) {
        istream_paragraph_iterator previous(*this);
        ++*this;
        return previous;
    }

    bool operator==(const istream_paragraph_iterator& other) const {
        return stream == other.stream;
    }

    bool operator!=(const istream_paragraph_iterator& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

};
```

Then you can write the input algorithm using `std::copy()` as well:

```
std::copy(istream_paragraph_iterator(in),
    istream_paragraph_iterator(),
    std::back_inserter(container));
```

Separating the logic into an iterator type lets you make the input and output algorithms parameterisable, and thus more general. In a template library, that’s typically a good thing. I would avoid adding overloads for standard containers, because you cannot know that they do the right thing on every platform; iterator-based algorithms are more portable, and you don’t have to write all the `template<template<...> class ...>` cruft.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that the number of template arguments in standard containers is not mandated by the standard, which means that your code will fail in any platform where there are any extra arguments.

In general I would not provide operator overloads for types that you have not defined, and in particular for standard containers. The reason is that you cannot do it *properly*. In particular you cannot *declare* them in the namespace where the container is, and that means that ADL will not do it's magic to pick the correct overload. If you want a helper function, you should provide a *named* function, where it will be simpler to help with lookup if needed.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template < template<typename,typename> class Container >
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, Container<std::string> const & c );
namespace A {
   struct S {};
   std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, S const & );
   void f() {
      std::vector<std::string> v;
      std::cout << v;
   }
}
int main() {
   A::f();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. You are quite right, I totally overlooked the implications when different namespaces come into play

Comment: @Martin: I have seen your edit request. I have thus modified the code to fail appropriately. Note that there is no need for the template or function definitions, and that the names of the template arguments to the template template argument would not be needed event then (and less so the default value)

Comment: On Ideone your code without struct S and the according operator still fails with: prog.cpp:6: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
prog.cpp:5: error: provided for ‘template<class, class> class Container’. http://ideone.com/5uMxO One template parameter of std::vector has a default value. That's why IMHO the full specification might be necessary. I added the template definitions to have the code running if struct S was not present.